# Ubuntu 14.04 / 14.10 is crashing on me

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I have no idea what is going on with my computer. I built it two years ago and I have been using Ubuntu on it since Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) and have upgraded them all with no problem.  I am running Ubuntu 14.10 right now and I put Gnome 3.12 on it.

I don't know what happened but all of a sudden when I run Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 14.10 it crashes at varying times. I do not know what triggers it but after 20, 30, 60 minutes I can not do anything on my desktop. Can't click buttons, switch windows anything.  Then my screen says No Sync and what ever I am listening to starts skipping.

Sorry I do not have any more information.  So how can I help you help me? Are there any crash logs I should submit, commands I should run that would give you more information?

EDIT:
I have 22.7 GB out of 967 GB disk space used.

Comment: It might be a hardware issue. Try testing a live system and run memtest. These might give you clues to discover the cause.

Answer (score 0):

just check whether your disk is full.
using 
**df -h**

if it is above 70% try to delete the content in your system.
if your GUI is not responding try through **alt+f6**

Comment: No I only have 22.7GB out of 967 GB used.